# Is possible to configure Log4net to clean log files but not by day?

Tags: c#, log4net

Nowadays I have the following configuration:

```
 <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\temp\log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MutexLock" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="[%thread]; %-5level; %date{yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.fff}; [%logger]; %message; %newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

With this configuration I am getting a lot of log files (100 log files by day), for example:

```
DAY 20:
log.txt.2016-07-20.1
log.txt.2016-07-20.2
...
log.txt.2016-07-20.100

DAY 21:
log.txt.2016-07-21.1
log.txt.2016-07-21.2
...
log.txt.2016-07-21.100
```

I would like to control files being 100 files total, and not 100 files by day. How could I control like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the [`RollingStyle`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingStyle.html) so that defaults to [`RollingMode.Composite`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.html)

> Composite: Roll files based on both the size and date of the file

This is why you are getting `maxSizeRollBackups` per day, as the default date rollover is once per day.

You only want to roll by size and not date, so you should add this to the appender config:

```
<rollingStyle value="Size" />
```

There's more detail in the [config examples for RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#RollingFileAppender)

Comment: It works perfectly. Before I was doing just overriding the date pattern (<datePattern value="" />), but this official configuration is better.